# Why is Text onTapGesture not working for widened frame in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have this testing file that is not working how I expect it to.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State var boolTest = false
    
    var nums = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(nums, id: \.self) { num in
                Text("\(num)")
                    .frame(width: 400)
                    .font(.system(size: 70))
                    .foregroundColor(boolTest ? .red : .green)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        boolTest.toggle()
                    }
            }

        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

When I tap on a number, the foreground color changes as expected. However, I want to be able to tap on the areas left and right of the `Text("\(num)")` so I expanded the frame modifier to test. However the color only changes when I tap directly on the number or text.

How do I tap on the space left or right of the number and have it change colors instead of it doing nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system treats the "invisible" (ie doesn't have visible drawn content) part of the view as unresponsive unless you set a `contentShape` on it.

```
//...
.frame(width: 400)
.contentShape(Rectangle())
//...
```

Comment: This worked for me also for Entity()